# Blender UI Screen Flashes on refreshing

Tags: interface

Can anybody tell me why this occurs frequently or is it my system graphics card issue....I am a newbie and any fix would be appreciated..thanks[image]

Comment: Looks a lot like a graphic card malfunction (probably VRAM related). Do you encounter similar glitches outside Blender ? Are you using the latest drivers ?

Comment: Update your graphics driver, verify that your GPU works properly in other software (e.g. GPU Benchmark) and check that your hardware fulfills the [minimum requirements for running Blender 2.8x](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).